# React cannot get state from redux in child component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have component that include other child component. Both try to get same state from redux. But parent component do it successfully, for child is null. Code is the  same. What I am doing wrong?

Parant component

```
import './home.css';

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Tabs, Tab, TabList, TabPanel } from 'react-tabs';

import { getSession } from 'app/shared/reducers/authentication';
import { createNewTab } from 'app/modules/home/code_tab.reducer';
import { Editor } from 'app/modules/home/editor';

export interface IHomeProp extends StateProps, DispatchProps {}

export class Home extends React.Component<IHomeProp> {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getSession();
  }  

  render() {  

    return (
      <Editor />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = storeState => ({
  codeTabs: storeState.codeTab.code_tabs
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { createNewTab };

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
type DispatchProps = typeof mapDispatchToProps;

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Home);
```

The child component is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Controlled as CodeMirror } from 'react-codemirror2';
import { createNewTab } from 'app/modules/home/code_tab.reducer';
import 'react-tabs/style/react-tabs.css';
import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';
import 'codemirror/theme/material.css';
require('codemirror/mode/xml/xml');

export interface IEditorProp extends StateProps, DispatchProps {}

export class Editor extends React.Component<IEditorProp> {
  render() {
    console.log(this);
    return <div>lala</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = storeState => ({
  codeTabs: storeState.codeTab.code_tabs
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {};

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
type DispatchProps = typeof mapDispatchToProps;

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Editor);
```

So in first case codeTabs in props is not null, but in second it is. Also I've noticed that init of codeTabs in Editor happened before Home.

Reducer is:

```
import axios from 'axios';

import { REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE } from 'app/shared/reducers/action-type.util';
import { ICodeTab } from '../../shared/model/code_tab.model';

export const ACTION_TYPES = {
  ADD_NEW_TAB: 'code_tab/ADD_NEW_TAB',
  GET_ALL: 'code_tab/GET_ALL'
};

const initialState = {
  code_tabs: [] as ICodeTab[]
};

export type CodeTabState = Readonly<typeof initialState>;

// Reducer
export default (state: CodeTabState = initialState, action): CodeTabState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTION_TYPES.ADD_NEW_TAB:
      const tab = new ICodeTab();
      return {
        ...state,
        code_tabs: [...state.code_tabs, tab]
      };
    case ACTION_TYPES.GET_ALL:
      return {
        ...state
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const apiUrl = 'api/account';

export const createNewTab = () => ({
  type: ACTION_TYPES.ADD_NEW_TAB
});

export const getAll = () => ({
  type: ACTION_TYPES.GET_ALL
});
```

Comment: Try console.log(codeTabs) in the render method and say what it logs please.
Also, posting the reducer can be helpful.
Another question -why do you export default Editor & Home with connect and also exporting it by itself?

Comment: @S.Haviv it is null in render. about export just copied code